# Is it possible to create an index relating two deviations but preserving the signal of one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have three temperatures I would like to compare. One is the body temperature ($T_{b}$), another is the reference ($T_{ref}$) and a third is the environment ($T_e$).

I would like to create an index that represents how different is the deviation from $T_{b}$ to $T_{ref}$ compared to the deviation of $T_{e}$ to $T_{ref}$. However, I would like to also convey the information of whether of the $T_{b}> T_{ref}$ or $T_{b}< T_{ref}$, hopefully by the signal of the index.

I have found two solutions in the literature but none preserve both characteristics:

$$ I_1 = \frac{T_b - T_{ref}}{T_e - T_{ref}} $$

This one compares both deviations (when they are equal $I_1 =1$) the value but does not preserve the signal (if $I_1>0$ I will not be sure if it is because $T_b-T_{ref}>0$ or $T_b-T_{ref}<0 \; and \; T_e-T_{ref}<0$).

Another alternative is:

$$ I_2 = (T_b - T_{ref})-(T_e - T_{ref}) $$

Which does keep some information on the $T_b$ signal. However, this one is mathematically equivalent to $T_b-T_e$ and thus do not consider $T_{ref}$ at all.

Is there an easy index that considers all three temperatures but keeps the information of $T_{b}> T_{ref}$ or $T_{b}< T_{ref}$?

Comment: If I understand your questions correctly, would $I_3 = (T_b - T_{ref})/|T_e - T_{ref}|$ have the properties you want? The denominator is simply the absolute value of the deviation of the environment from the reference. Note that your requirements do not uniquely identify such a choice. For example, $I_4(S) = (T_b - T_{ref})/(S + |T_e - T_{ref}|)$ is another choice for any temperature $S$. (And one that behaves better when $T_e$ and $T_{ref}$ are very close to each other!)

Comment: I think the $I_3$ is close to what I need, but it still has the problem when  $T_b = 30, T_p=25, T_e=20$, i.e a case where $T_b$ and $T_e$ are in equidistant to $T_ref$ but in opposite ends. In that case the value would be of $I_3=1$, which gives the impression they have the same deviation when their deviation has opposite signs.

Comment: I think you need to specify clearly what conditions you want your function to obey. As worded, this is too vague to answer.